# javascript accordian menu how to move plus symbol to left side from right side

Tags: javascript, css, accordion, accordionpane

I am using an accordian menu from the url below.  The menu has plus symbol on the right side.  I would like to move the plus symbole to the left side but I can't figure out how to do that.

Any advice, will be greatly appreciated.
[Dynamic Drive accordian menu](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ddaccordionmenu-glossy.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styles:

```
.glossymenu a.menuitem .statusicon {
    left: 5px;
    right: auto;
}

a.menuitem.submenuheader {
    padding-left: 24px;
}
```

Then it will be on the left side instead of being on the right side. The `.statusicon` is already absolutely positioned within the element, so all you have to do is reposition it to be 5px from the left side instead of its current default, 5px from the right side. The padding is to create a space for the icon.

Comment: WOW!   Joeytje50  You Are Brilliant!  That's amazing, perfect solution. Thank You!